# problem with shell new line when output to file

Tags: shell

i have a problem when I want to output several variables to txt file in shell. I want them in one line, but there appear line break after first and third variable. I have for example this

```
for s in `ls $TESTDIR/results_orig.txt`
    do 
        t_a=(`grep "    a" $s`);
        t_b=(`grep "Bytes written to file: " $s`);
        t_c=(`grep " Total Time:" $s`);
        t_d=(`grep "QP                           " $s`);

        a=${t_a[2]};
        b=${t_b[4]};
        c=${t_c[3]};    
        d=${t_d[2]};

        echo "$a $b $c $d" >> $TESTDIR/results.txt;
    done
```

I got the variables t_a to t_d are after I parse original txt file to find some values in it. Than I want to find some number ant write them in file without other text that I have in original file. And I want it to write those parsed numbers in one line in new file, like

`13.2 1678 3231.5 2422.1`

And I get

`13.2
 1678 3231.5
 2422.1`

When I echo any variable separately to the console I get right values. So variables are parsed fine. What could be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: what are the "t_*" variables value?

Comment: Can you check whether the data itself contains new lines?

Comment: I updated the post. @PriyaAgarwal probably that is the problem, but I do not know how to check it and eventually how to remove it.

Comment: 1) please use `$()` instead of \` 2) please use `awk` 3) you don't need the `;` at the end of the line 4) what shebang do you use?

Comment: I use  #!/bin/bash

Comment: do you mean `cat $TESTDIR/results_orig.txt`...

Comment: You can trim for new lines while assigning values to variables. like  - t_a=(`grep "    a" $s|tr -d '\n`). See if this helps.

Comment: @PriyaAgarwal It worked when i used \r. Thank you!

Comment: Consider posting sample data - it will help SO contributors to help you.